# Export or Batch script Windows VPN Network Connection

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp

We use a Windows PPTP VPN connection to get onto our network's VPN.

Is there a way I can write a batch script or export my settings to add this VPN connection to another person's computer. I also need to be able to set certain things like "Do not use default gateway" and add a WINS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Connection Manager Administation Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739464(WS.10).aspx). You can use this tool to create a program to automatically configure client computers with a "connection" to your VPN server. It's actaully rather nice to use. We take the output from the CMAK and deploy it onto clients with startup scripts, but you could definitely email the resulting EXE (or a link thereto) to clients for them to execute.

The CMAK is an Add/Remove Windows Components option in Windows Server 2003 and an a "feature" (if I recall properly) on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If anywhere this would probably be in the registry somewhere.  You might be able to export/import that way.

You could also use something like powershell.